# WPF Programmatically binding Two way

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to bind a pair of ToggleButtons, so when one is checked, the other is also checked.

```
ToggleButton two = new ToggleButton();
/* Set up ToggleButton here*/
ToggleButton one = this.somePanel.Children.FirstOrDefault(/*Some Condition*/) as ToggleButton
if (one == null) return;
Binding binding = new Binding("IsChecked");
binding.Source = two;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
one.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
/* Add two to the UI */
```

When I toggle button one, button two toggles, however, when I toggle button two, button one does not toggle.

Comment: Don't create bindings in code, it's a mess.

Comment: So you want toggle buttons to do the opposite of what a normal toggle button does?  Why do you need a pair of buttons to be the same?

Comment: @Paparazzi They represent the same object on the server, but are in different menu's

Comment: Then do proper binding to the same property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `IsChecked` property of both buttons to the same property in your `ViewModel`.

In `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Width="60"
                  Height="30"
                  Content="Button 1"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleButtonChecked}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="60"
                  Height="30"
                  Content="Button 2"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleButtonChecked}" />
```

In `MainViewModel.cs` (assuming that you can use `MVVM Light`):

```
  private bool _isToggleButtonChecked = false;
    public bool IsToggleButtonChecked
    {
        get { return _isToggleButtonChecked; }
        set { Set<bool>(ref _isToggleButtonChecked, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any issue with your code. It seems to work perfect at my end. I have tried both in xaml and codebehind as well as entirely in code behind.

Both works as expected and Binding is perfect!

I have included a sample below. Check it. The binding works perfect at my end!

**XAML :**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
 >
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" />
</Window>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ToggleButton two = new ToggleButton();
            two.Content = "Two";
            two.Width = 100;
            two.Height = 50;

            /* Set up ToggleButton here*/

            this.Grid1.Children.Add(two);

            ToggleButton one = new ToggleButton();
            if (one == null) return;
            one.Content = "One";
            one.Width = 100;
            one.Height = 50;
            one.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 250, 0);

            this.Grid1.Children.Add(one);

            Binding binding = new Binding("IsChecked");
            binding.Source = two;
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            one.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
            /* Add two to the UI */
        }
    }
}
```